# How to handle backend auth with express as reverse proxy api

Tags: express, authentication, cookies, setcookie

I am using express the first time in a project as a kind of reverse proxy in between my frontend and backend. The backend authentication is cookie based.
First I was using http-proxy-middleware to make my requests. This works fine and the cookie gets passed no problem.

The problem is that I want to decouple the front and backend as the api isn't very usable right now (for example 3 requests necessary to get data for one view). So instead of making requests directly I want to have my express server handle the heavy lifting in the background.

Currently I am using axios for the requests and pass the cookie through with the request and the new one back with the response. This works fine but feels very hacky and error prone. For example I have to split the returned setcookie string in a very weird way.

```
app.get('/api/myrequest', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('backendserver/url', {
    headers: {
      Cookie: req.cookies['auth'],
    },
    responseType: 'json',
  })
  .then((response) => {
    let tempCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'][0];
    tempCookie = tempCookie.split(';')[0];
    tempCookie = tempCookie.split('=');

    res.cookie(tempCookie[0], tempCookie[1]);
    res.send(response.data);
  })
});
```

I suppose there is a much better way to handle this. I was looking at things like passportjs but am not sure if it fits this special use case as the auth isn't handled by express itself.
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?